# Bootstrap 3 and Haml - Adjust button width

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have the following haml code in my rails 4 view, using bootstrap 3:

```
%div{:class => 'btn-group'}
  %button{:class => 'btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle', :type => 'button', 'data-toggle'.to_sym => 'dropdown'}
    %span{:class => 'caret'}
    %span{:class => 'sr-only'} Toggle Dropdown
  %ul{:class => 'dropdown-menu'}
    %a{:class => 'close_task', :name => 'name', :href => '#' } Close
```

This renders an incredibly small button, despite the button class of `btn-lg`. I'm new to haml, so what am I missing that is causing this button to be so small here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a text to the button, so **css would be applied around it**. For example:

> %button{:class => 'btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle', :type =>
>   'button', 'data-toggle'.to_sym => 'dropdown'} MyButton

In your case, there is no text for the button. It requires at least one non blank character to apply styling .
Above will create a large size bootstrap button with the text `MyButton`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-sizing), you might want to try to size the button group itself instead of the button's nested inside of the button group.

```
%div{:class => 'btn-group btn-group-lg'}
  %button{:class => 'btn btn-default dropdown-toggle', :type => 'button', 'data-toggle' => 'dropdown'}
    %span{:class => 'caret'}
    %span{:class => 'sr-only'} Toggle Dropdown
  %ul{:class => 'dropdown-menu'}
    %a{:class => 'close_task', :name => 'name', :href => '#' } Close
```